# How to dynamically reference razor components like Vue?

Tags: blazor

Normally with Vue.js you would reference a component in markup similar to Blazor as so:

```
<UserImageComponent>
    ...
</UserImageComponent>
```

However, Vue.js has the ability to load a component dynmically:

```
<component v-bind:is="UserImageComponent">
    ...
</component>
```

Does Blazor have something like this?

Comment: This is most likely not possible at the moment because the razor page is compiled to intermediate C# code which is then executed. I assume you have to build your own logic in that page to implement a similar behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy way around is to build a basically empty component, give it a ChildContent parameter and set that to anything you like.

```
[Parameter]
public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }
```

The RenderFragment will render anything you throw in there, even if it's another component or if you set it dynamically.

Comment: tip: the property `has-to-be-named` ChildContent